# How to change a second select list based on the first select list option when values are dynamic?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have php page for vehicle search filter which have 2 types of vehicle that is RV's and campervans and also have two selects

```
<div class="fields">
<p>Vehicle Type</p>
<select class="car" name="car_type" id="car_type">
<option value="0">Select Vehicle</option>
    <?php if(count($vehicleType) > 0 ){
        foreach($vehicleType as $vt){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $vt ?>" <?=isset($_GET['car_type'])&&$_GET['car_type']==$vt?'selected':'';?> ><?php echo $vt ?></option>
    <?php   }

    } ?>
</select>
</div>

<div class="fields">
<p>Total No. of Passengers*</p>


<select class="half" name="passengers" id="passengers">
<option>No. of Passengers</option>
        <option <?php if(@$_REQUEST['passengers'] == 1){?>selected<?php }?>>1</option>
    <option <?php if(@$_REQUEST['passengers'] == 2){?>selected<?php }?>>2</option>
    <option <?php if(@$_REQUEST['passengers'] == 3){?>selected<?php } ?>>3</option>
    <option <?php if(@$_REQUEST['passengers'] == 4){?>selected<?php }?>>4</option>
      <option <?php if(@$_REQUEST['passengers'] == 5){?>selected<?php }?>>5</option>
      <option <?php if(@$_REQUEST['passengers'] == 6){?>selected<?php }?>>6</option>
      <option <?php if(@$_REQUEST['passengers'] == 7){?>selected<?php }?>>7</option>
    <option <?php if(@$_REQUEST['passengers'] == 8){?>selected<?php }?>>8</option>

</select>
</div>
```

How do I do that with jQuery or php if I choose "Rv" in the first select? The second select would show me 8 passengers . If I choose Campervan in the first select, the second select would show me 5 passengers..

Comment: yes you need to write javascript code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do something along these lines:

```
<?php
$number_of_passengers = 8;
if(!empty($_REQUEST['car_type'])) {
    $number_of_passengers = $_REQUEST['car_type'] == 'Campervans' ? 5 : 8;
}

$passengers = 0;
if(!empty($_REQUEST['passengers'])){
    $passengers = (int) $_REQUEST['passengers'];
}
?>

<select class="car" name="car_type" id="car_type">
    <option value="0">Select Vehicle</option>
    <option value="RV/Motorhome">RV/Motorhome</option>
    <option value="Campervans">Campervans</option>
</select>

<select class="half" name="passengers" id="passengers">
    <option>No. of Passengers</option>
    <?php
    for($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_passengers; $i++) {
        ?>
        <option
            <?php
                if($i == $passengers) {
                    echo ' selected ';
                }
            ?>
            >
            <?php echo $i ?>
        </option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#car_type').change(function() {

        $("#passengers").children().removeAttr("selected");

        if ($(this).val() === 'Campervans') {
            $('#passengers option:nth-child(n+7)').hide();
        } else {
            $('#passengers option').show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

There are cleaner ways of doing this but this should serve to get the point across.

Few things to note about the PHP:

1. See how I check if the `$_REQUEST` key is available using [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) - this avoids having to use `@` which is generally not a good idea.
2. I am using a loop to echo the options in the passenger select to avoid code repetition because typing that out 8 times is boring ;-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but it shows nothing in the passengers field also please check my updated question so you understand better

Comment: @NeerajMishra - I edited the code to instantiate `$number_of_passengers`. Let me know if that works for you now.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Vehicle\index.php on line 150

Comment: Missing semi colon on the first line - my bad!

Comment: @NeerajMishra - no problem!  If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @ Bananaapple  WHn i click on search it gives some error like " Notice: Use of undefined constant Campervans - assumed 'Campervans' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Vehicle\index.php on line 137 "

Comment: On that line all you need to do is put the word `Campervans` in to quotes so it becomes `'Campervans'` - that way you explicitly tell PHP you are giving it a string ths removing the notice.

Comment: @ Bananaapple you are genius man..Thanks ..Will you please help me on another task

Comment: http://i.prntscr.com/4eOhvYK5QiCWlaexl11_bQ.png ...select box works fine when i select rv from vehicle type and click on search it works perfect and then again when i select campervans then selectbox shows 5 but by default it reamins at same

Comment: i.prntscr.com/4eOhvYK5QiCWlaexl11_bQ.png ...select box works fine when i select rv from vehicle type and no. of passengers 7 and then  click on search it works perfect and then again when i select campervans then selectbox shows 5 but by default it reamins at same @Bananaapple

Comment: If I understand you right we need to flush the selection on passengers when the vehicle select changes - try adding the new line I put into the JS.

Comment: @ Bananaapple CAN we PUT 2 as the default selected value for Number of Passengers

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to add javascript code for that.
insert below code in your page and check if this is what you want?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.car').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() === 'RV/Motorhome'){
        $('.half').find('option').show()
    }else if($(this).val() === 'Campervans'){
     $('.half').find('option').slice(6).hide();
     }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: but it still shows 8 passengers in the select bos .. ionly want to show 5